# How convert sql dump file in json/csv

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mongodb

On my node.js server I have a route where I get mysql dump file in zip extension. In my app I'm using MongoDB database. How can I convert this dump.zip file to json or csv and store data into my MongoDB database?

Comment: Please provide some code, that shows you effort . From there we can help you out, if you are facing an issue but if you haven't started anything try to look for packages on NPM that unzips the zip file and then read file from there on. Everything have documentation try something and update your question

Comment: a sql dump is a collection of SQL staements to re-create the tables and to fill them with data. so you don't have directly an object that contains the data only